# Pushout of categories along embeddings gives homotopy pushout?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

Consider the pushout of a diagram $A\leftarrow B\rightarrow C$ of categories and assume that at least one of the arrows is an embedding, i.e. injective on objects and arrows. When applying the nerve functor to the pushout diagram, do we get a homotopy pushout in simplicial sets?

Comment: "injective on objects" is an evil condition. Don't you want something like $F(X)\cong F(Y)\implies X\cong Y$ or (stronger) "F reflects isomorphisms" ?

Comment: @JohannesHahn: "injective on objects" is evil, but so is "pushout"; if the question involves evil concepts, then the answer may do as well.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Why is a pushout evil? It is a limit...

Comment: @JohannesHahn: limits and colimits of categories are usually evil.  That is why people consider 2-(co)limits or homotopy (co)limits instead.

Comment: Do all these "evil" connotations apply to groupoids, and higher groupoids?  I like colimits of groupoids and higher groupoids, and have used them for specific homotopy invariant calculations. The higher case  led to the notion of nonabelian tensor product of groups, in work with Loday. Can someone please give me an example of an algebraic calculation  using homotopy 2-colimits?

Comment: Of course, the "right" way to check this is to see if there is a model structure on categories where such an embedding is a cofibration.  This fails in the standard model structure (see here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+model+structure), and of course by Werner's counterexample below must fail in general (or at least for any left proper model structure, meaning that you only need one of your maps to be a cofibration in order to compute a homotopy pushout).

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee: I don't understand what you're saying. The types of maps the OP calls 'embeddings' are in particular cofibrations in the canonical model structure on Cat. The given diagram *is* a homotopy pushout in Cat, it's just that the nerve functor does not preserve pushouts (homotopy or otherwise).

Comment: @DylanWilson Oh, I expected from the "freeness" alluded to there that there'd be more to being a cofibration than just being an embedding.  Anyways, you're right that I addressed the wrong question -- I read "homotopy pushout" and mistakenly thought we were still working in categories!  Perhaps the better categorically-minded thing to say here is that the nerve is right adjoint (to the "fundamental category" functor), so shouldn't be expected to preserve many colimits.

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee: In the 1-category case cofibrations just need to be injective on objects, there's no condition on morphisms.

Comment: btw, the statement seems to hold if you replace embedding by (pseudo) Dwyer morphism. See e.g Raptis "Homotopy Theory of Posets"

Comment: In general, the homotopy colimit of a diagram of categories was defined by Thomason (in his thesis) using the Grothendieck construction, and he proved that the nerve functor carries this categorical homotopy colimit to the (topological) homotopy colimit of the nerves of the categories.

Comment: So if you have a particular pushout diagram that you're trying to study (maybe the one in your other question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160753/reducing-the-simplices-in-the-nerve-of-a-category-with-an-object-with-trivial-en) you might want to compare the pushout to Thomason's homotopy pushout.

Comment: @DanRamras: Maybe it's worth noting that Thomason's notion is a homotopy pushout with respect to a different set of equivalences (namely, those maps of categories inducing an equivalence on their groupoid completions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is wrong. Let $B=\mathbb{N}$, $A$ the cone over $B$ and $C$ the cocone over $B$. The pushout category is contractible, since it has an initial and a terminal object. But the homotopy pushout on the nerve level is the homotopy type of a $2$-sphere.

Comment: I guess you are taking $B$ to be a one-object category rather than a poset-category?

Comment: Yes, one object category. You can take any monoid which is not contractible.